# Jenkins configurations gets reverted by SYSTEM user anomaly

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline, salt-stack

I am running Jenkins version 2.85 on Kubernetes as pod(Affinity set to one workernode). I am creating Jobs using [Salt Jenkins module](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/modules/all/salt.modules.jenkins.html) by passing XML to this module.

I am using Jenkins Global Library for preforming job execution.

My Job config looks like this[image]
[image][image]

I am calling GobalLibrary with my parameters like repoURL, componet etc..,

Things goes well for weeks and now I landed to a weird situation where my job configurations(config.xml) gets updated/revert automatically.

Intermittently my "Build with parameter" options disappears and I can see only "Build now" in Jenkins GUI. Initially I thought someone is doing this, so to track the config changes I installed Job config history plugin in Jenkins and what I find is strange. Someone with "SYSTEM" username is making/reverting changes.

This is how it looks

[image]

and what I find is SYSTEM user revert only JOB config changes, not the PIPELINE.

[image]
[image]

I am not sure what's going wrong behind the scenes and how to stop or fix this. This is my Production instance so I am more worried.

I can see a SYSTEM user in my Jenkins

[image]

but I can not delete that user

[image]

Few relevant Question I find for this but with no answers

[Configuration of Jobs getting updated by System user on Jenkins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25642612/configuration-of-jobs-getting-updated-by-system-user-on-jenkins)

[Jenkins SYSTEM user removes custom workspace configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34316773/jenkins-system-user-removes-custom-workspace-configuration)

I am not sure if this Jenkins Bug or some plugin is playing with my soul.

Need help! :(

Comment: Issue created on Jenkins: JENKINS-51160 - SYSTEM user changing/reverting configurations of Parameterised job used with Jenkins Global pipeline library

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay I find the answer to this problem.

I have used **properties** in my Jekins Global Library something like this

```
// Disable concurrent builds
//properties([disableConcurrentBuilds()])
```

which overrides my external job configuration(done via salt).

Hint I get from this blog:
https://st-g.de/2016/12/parametrized-jenkins-pipelines

Comment: Exact same problem, exact same solution.  Man I feel dumb!

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem. For me it was solved when I changed the Build triggers -> Build Periodically settings from 'H 23 * * *' to '00 23 * * *'. (As I want my build to execute every night at 23:00.) Where H lets Jenkins decide when to run the job somewhere between 23:00 and 23:59 to spread load evenly. It seems Jenkins sometimes decided that it would be best to run my job on a different server and changed the parameters automatically.

Comment: That's not the issue above. Its is a bug in the pipeline code I did unintentionally.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the issue was that the Jenkinsfile was removing the parameters I added to the pipeline from Jenkins console. Adding the same parameters in the JenkinSfile (stage -> script -> properties -> parameters) solved the issue.

In a nutshell, make sure that your Pipeline script is using the same configuration that your pipeline uses.

Jenkins documentation on parameters: https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#parameters