# Any configuration changes made in Jenkins which is installed in AWS EKS cluster disappear in 30 mins

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes-helm, amazon-eks

Any configuration changes in "ManageJenkins" page like "configure global security","Manage cloud and Nodes","Configure system" etc disappear in 30 mins.

Jenkins is installed in AWS EKS cluster.
Using the LTS jenkins 2.263.1. Installed the jenkins through helm installation and using EFS for the persistent storage.

Kindly help to resolve the issue.

Comment: If you have access to the server, try to analyze if something is wiping out your `config.xml` from particular location. Please share time interval from creation of job to deletion of job.

Comment: I can able to see the changes in config.xml, after the 30 min of interval , changes are wiped out. changes like no of executor, global security changes, changes in nodes and clouds etc disappear in the config file but Jobs are stable.

Comment: There is some system configuration which you have done which is causing this. Can you install a plugins which can help you track changes and find audit data? Please look at this post for example: `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50192880/jenkins-configurations-gets-reverted-by-system-user-anomaly`